# Minification Task in Gradle

Tags: javascript, gradle, minify

I am trying to implement minification task in Gradle. Following is my code :-

```
plugins {
    id "com.eriwen.gradle.js" version "2.14.1"
}

import com.eriwen.gradle.js.tasks.MinifyJsTask    
task minify() {
        def index       = 1
        def dynNames    = []
        javascript.source {
            custom {
                js {
                    srcDir "$pExplodedFolderPath"
                    include "**/*.js"
                    exclude "**/*.min.js"
                }
            }
        }

        javascript.source.custom.js.files.eachWithIndex {fileSrc, idx ->
            def dynName = "minifyTask_${index++}"

            task "${dynName}"(type:MinifyJsTask) {

                source = file(fileSrc.absolutePath)
                dest = "/Users/user.name/Documents/" + fileSrc.getParentFile().getName() + "/" + fileSrc.name + ".min.js"
                closure {
                    warningLevel = 'DEBUG'
                        compilationLevel = 'SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS'
                }

            }

            dynNames << dynName
        }

        dependsOn dynNames

    }
```

When I run it, it prints "NO-SOURCE" for all the files. Can anybody help what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to wrap your task action into `doLast {}`. The way you wrote it the code is executed during configuration phase, and always, no matter whether the task should run or not.

Comment: But if i 'println', I can see all files. Doesn't this mean it should work ?
If not, can you give me a small example through my code ? Which part to put in doLast ?

Comment: As I said, your code **is** run, but at the **wrong time**. In Gradle you have initialization phase, configuration phase and execution phase. Your code is run in configuration phase no matter whether the task should run or not and during execution phase, there is nothing to do for your task, so it is skipped with `NO-SOURCE`.

Comment: Vampire : It would really help if you could give out an example based on my code. I know the three phases of Gradle, but wherever I am seeing examples, I am not seeing a doLast required. Example :
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Canadensys/canadensys-common/master/gradle/canadensys_web_build.gradle

a little more Help is requested.
Thanks

Comment: `<<` is a deprecated shortcut for `doLast `. Just wrap all the code that should be executed at execution phase in a `doLast ` block and read the user guide to get a grip on advanced Gradle usage. ;-)